# Unknown provider $resource in config(function ($resource) {...}) after including ngResource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Gets error: `Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $resource from accessServices`. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

```
angular.module('accessServices', ['ngResource']).

  config(function ($resource) {
    this.accesses = ['createuser'];
    this.AclResource = $resource('/api/v1', {}, {
      list: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true}
    });
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [config method](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#config) is for configuring the module and set up the providers, you can't inject `$resource` service (but you can inject the `$resourceProvider`). Anyway, it looks like you're creating a service so you probably want to use the factory method:

```
angular.module('accessServices', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('AclResource',function ($resource) {
  ...
```